# Run BHO inside embedded IE control within third-party desktop application

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, bho

I have a third-party windows desktop .Net application with embedded Internet Explorer control. I want to run my BHO from that IE control. BHO dosn't have any GUI, it just captures users' actions.

Is it possible? Probably I can use Windows Hooks API to embed by BHO's dll, find IE contol with reflection and register my BHO. But it sounds a little bit scary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no supported way to load/run a BHO inside a Web Browser control. You're correct to note that you could, conceivably, write code that loads the BHO and calls SetSite on the control using the Web Browser Control's handle. However, the BHO may not work in such an environment if it has dependencies on other objects present in IE but not in the Web Browser control.

Backing up a bit-- what does your BHO do and why do you need to load it into someone else's program?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is some more information about my task. Our customer has a CRM system that is implemented as a desktop app with embedded IE controls. Actually it's a web app that uses desktop app's menus and tabs for navigation. The customer wants to log all users' actions. We already have a BHO that records IE users actions. But now I see that it's not a solution for this task. I'm going to try to embed some javascript  into that webapp to track users actions (like in search engine analytics tools)